# How to pass CancellationToken to WebApi action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I'm making a request to a WebApi as follows:

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, dto).Result;
```

I'm using `HostingEnvironment` in the controller action so I can do the work in a background thread, and pass IIS's cancellation token to my service method, as follows:

```
public IHttpActionResult MyAction(SearchDto dto)
{
    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async ct =>
    {
        //Do background work
        var result = await myService.DoWorkAsync(dto, ct);
    });

    return Ok();
}
```

Now I want to pass a cancellation token from the client, so that the user can cancel the request, so I created a `CancellationTokenSource` and did the following change on the client:

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, dto, cts.Token).Result;
```

And the change to the action:

```
public IHttpActionResult MyAction(SearchDto dto, CancellationToken ct)
{
    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async ct =>
    {
        //Do background work
        var result = await myService.DoWorkAsync(dto, ct);
    });

    return Ok();
}
```

My problem is the line:

> HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async ct =>

If I need to the use the `ct` I pass to the action, how am I going to use the `ct` that IIS needs to pass to the background thread?

Comment: Not sure this will work. Once the token is send to the server and the user cancelled it, then the server won't be notified would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is combine the two cancellation tokens you've got, the first from the client and the second from the `HostingEnvironment`. You can do this with this [CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=netframework-4.7.2) method

```
public IHttpActionResult MyAction(SearchDto dto, CancellationToken ct1)
{
    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async ct2 =>
    {
        using (var linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct1, ct2))
        {
            var result = await myService.DoWorkAsync(dto, linkedCts.Token);
        }
    });

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does this work? The client sends the requests, then cancels the token (ct1) **client side**, then the server magically knows ct1 is cancelled? Is there another request send by the client in this case or... ?

Comment: That's my assumption too. But why is there CancellationToken on async requests?